# Why does EnsureCoreWebView2Async only return in OnContentRendered

Tags: webview2

I'm trying to use [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/wpf) in a WPF (.NET Framework) application, and I'm puzzled by the method `EnsureCoreWebView2Async`.

I followed the Getting Started article, and surely enough it was not working for me. The method `EnsureCoreWebView2Async` would *never* return.

Took a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66829201/webview2-ensurecorewebview2async-never-returns) which suggests (with no further explanation) to call the method in the `OnContentRendered` callback.

While this works, is there any reason why this happens ? With the following code :

```
public partial class DocumentationWindow : Window
{
    public DocumentationWindow(Window owner, DocumentationViewModel vm)
    {
        Owner = owner;
        DataContext = vm;
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeAsync();
    }

    private async void InitializeAsync()
    {
        await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null); // This will never return
    }
    
    protected override async void OnContentRendered(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnContentRendered(e);
        await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(); // This will work just fine
    }
}
```

The [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.wpf.webview2.ensurecorewebview2async?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1210.39) states

> Note that even though this method is asynchronous and returns a Task,
> it still must be called on the UI thread like most public
> functionality of most UI controls.

Both the constructor and `OnContentRendered` are excecuted on the UI thread.

But somehow, the former will never return. Why is that ?