# WebView2 in WPF: EnsureCoreWebView2Async never finishes without any exception or error

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-6.0, webview2

*Note that [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66829201/webview2-ensurecorewebview2async-never-returns) is not a duplicate. I am having a different issue.*

My client computer cannot see WebView2 content in any WPF project. After some debugging effort, I pinpointed it to `EnsureCoreWebView2Async` call. I sent him a brand new WPF project with these code:

```cs
    private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.wv.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted += this.Wv_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted;
        MessageBox.Show("EnsureCoreWebView2Async is about to run");
        await this.wv.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
        MessageBox.Show("EnsureCoreWebView2Async finished");
    }

    private void Wv_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object? sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.InitializationException is not null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("EnsureCoreWebView2Async has exception: " + e.InitializationException);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("EnsureCoreWebView2Async successful: " + e.IsSuccess);
            this.wv.CoreWebView2.Navigate("https://www.example.com");
        }
    }
```

I even tried to wrap the code in `Window_Loaded` inside a `Dispatcher.Invoke()` call to make sure it's executed in a UI thread but it has the same result.

On all other computers that I tested (Windows 11 and 10), we see all messages that are supposed to show but on his computer (Windows 10, latest update) only "EnsureCoreWebView2Async is about to run" is showed. After that nothing happens at all. He has VS2022 installed and I tried debugging and stepping over `EnsureCoreWebView2Async` never ends.

We tried reinstalling .NET 6. Attempting to run WebView2 installation (Evergreen Bootstrapper download from [official website](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/)) results in message saying it's already installed.

I tried compiling on my computer and sent over to his computer, his computer would not show the website (call never finishes). I asked him to compile on his side and send over to me, my computer shows up the website just fine with all the messages showed so I am sure it's not because of the compiler/compiling environment.

So far I cannot find any second computer that has the same issue, but according to our Windows Store review, someone also has the issue (their UI is blank). I cannot find out what is causing the problem. Please advise us on how to debug this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As for my case, the issue is resolved by uninstalling his WebView2 Runtime (from Control Panel) and reinstall it, every works now. Guess now we will never know what is the cause.