# Programmatically Get UserAgent String from WebView2 Control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-agent, webview2

For WinForms and WinUI 3, I can use code like below to get the User Agent String of the WebView2 Control:

```
private async void GetDefaultUserAgentString()
{
    webViewForUaAgent = new WebView2();

    await webViewForUaAgent.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();

    webViewForUaAgent.NavigationCompleted += async (s, arg) =>
    {
        try
        {
            UserAgent = await webViewForUaAgent.ExecuteScriptAsync("eval('navigator.userAgent');");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             // Log exception
        }
    };

    // Now that we've set everything up, we can navigate
    // (previously, we were navigating _before_ setting up Load handler
    webViewForUaAgent.NavigateToString("<html></html>");
}
```

However, this code does not work for WPF.  It hangs on EnsureCoreWebView2Async as described in a number of other posts (e.g. [WebView2 EnsureCoreWebView2Async never returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66829201/webview2-ensurecorewebview2async-never-returns)), but the fixes for these posts all wait until the ContentRendered event before calling EnsureCoreWebView2Async, but I can't do this as I am writing a "plugin" that has no UI.

I have also tried waiting for the WebView2 Loaded event as described here : https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/911  Unfortunately, this also hangs for me.

Does someone know of a way to make this work, or of another way to get the User Agent String of WebView2?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/202) GitHub issue for more information and possible solutions for how to use the `WebView2` control in an GUI-less application.

The solutions seems to be use the `CreateCoreWebView2ControllerAsync` API.